# Passing a FileDescriptor to a VideoView

Tags: android, permissions, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm using the VideoView class to play back some media files, but the problem is these files reside within internal storage, and can't be played by simply passing their URLs due to a permissions issue. I've read up that this can be overcome by using a FileDescriptor instead, but I can't figure out exactly how to do that using the VideoView.

So far I've tried something like this, but the code within onPrepared is never reached:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(new FileInputStream(myFile).getFD());
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

videoView.start();
```

Comment: What specifically occurred? "to no avail" is not very specific. :-)

Comment: Sorry about that. The code was never reached.

Comment: `onPrepared()` will not be called until the media is prepared, and presumably you have not provided it with any media yet. I don't see a way to use a FD in the `VideoView` API. You might need to consider switching to using `MediaPlayer` directly with your own `TextureView` or `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Yea, was hoping I wouldn't have to do that. =( Thanks anyways.